# Elpy keeps prepending backslash to my python path

Tags: elpy

I am trying to set my Elpy on my home machine and, so far, everything works except actually running the Python interpreter. I normally launch the interpreter and run code via `C-c C-c`, but when I do that under the current install I get the following backtrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Searching for program" "No such  file or directory" "\\~/anaconda3/bin/python")
  make-process(:name "Python" :buffer #<buffer *Python*> :command ("\\~/anaconda3/bin/python" "-i"))
  apply(make-process (:name "Python" :buffer #<buffer *Python*> :command ("\\~/anaconda3/bin/python" "-i")))
  start-process("Python" #<buffer *Python*> "\\~/anaconda3/bin/python" "-i")
  apply(start-process "Python" #<buffer *Python*> "\\~/anaconda3/bin/python" "-i")
  start-file-process("Python" #<buffer *Python*> "\\~/anaconda3/bin/python" "-i")
  apply(start-file-process "Python" #<buffer *Python*> "\\~/anaconda3/bin/python" "-i")
  comint-exec-1("Python" #<buffer *Python*> "\\~/anaconda3/bin/python" ("-i"))
  comint-exec(#<buffer *Python*> "Python" "\\~/anaconda3/bin/python" nil ("-i"))
  make-comint-in-buffer("Python" "*Python*" "\\~/anaconda3/bin/python" nil "-i")
  apply(make-comint-in-buffer "Python" "*Python*" "\\~/anaconda3/bin/python" nil "-i")
  python-shell-make-comint("\\~/anaconda3/bin/python -i" "Python" t)
  run-python("\\~/anaconda3/bin/python -i" nil t)
  elpy-shell-get-or-create-process()
  elpy-shell--ensure-shell-running()
  elpy-shell-send-region-or-buffer-and-step(nil)
  funcall-interactively(elpy-shell-send-region-or-buffer-and-step nil)
  call-interactively(elpy-shell-send-region-or-buffer-and-step)
  elpy-shell--send-with-step-go(elpy-shell-send-region-or-buffer-and-step nil nil nil)
  elpy-shell-send-region-or-buffer(nil)
  funcall-interactively(elpy-shell-send-region-or-buffer nil)
  call-interactively(elpy-shell-send-region-or-buffer nil nil)
  command-execute(elpy-shell-send-region-or-buffer)
```

Obviously it is not finding my Python install under `\\~/anaconda3/bin/python`, most likely due to the prepended `\\` in my path (right?).  I ensured my paths are correct in my `.emacs` file and with `elpy-config`.  Does anyone have ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Do you see the same thing when starting Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: My guess is that `python-shell-interpreter` is wrongly set to `"\\~/anaconda3/bin/python"`. Don't rely on `elpy-config` but customize it yourself to `"~/anaconda3/bin/python"`.

Comment: I think that it might be actually trying to prevent tilde from being interpreted by the shell as your home directory. Just set it to the absolute path (if you need this to change based on the user running Emacs, then add the code to set it up in `init.el`?

Comment: @Drew Finally zeroed in on the problem.  I have '(python-shell-interpreter "~/anaconda3/bin/python") within custom-set-variables.  After commenting that out it runs fine (well, more or less fine...now the whole script gets printed to the interpreter when run, but that's something else to figure out).  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Tobias I thought that too, but I had my paths specified within .emacs as well.

Comment: @wvxvw I suspected that too, but I have the exact same configuration on other machines and it works fine.  HOWEVER, I changed the path to absolute on this machine and it works fine.  So, the problem was with: '(python-shell-interpreter "~/anaconda3/bin/python").  If I comment that out everything works fine.  If I change the path to absolute, everything works fine.  This is certainly unexpected behavior.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: My guess is that they'd do it because tilde has no special meaning in MS Windows, so, they wanted to avoid implicit expansion of shell variables... see if the version of Elpy you have that doesn't exhibit this behavior is the same as the one that does. Probably it's a recent addition.

Comment: If you have an answer, please post it as an answer, not just in comments. Comments can be deleted at any time. If you feel your answer is the best one, please accept it so the question does not show as having no accepted answer. If you feel someone posts a better answer later you can always change which answer is the accepted one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was the problem: I had "'(python-shell-interpreter "~/anaconda3/bin/python")" within custom-set-variables in .emacs.  At some point the tilde was being escaped (as wvxvw said, tilde has no special meaning in Windows environments).  So I replaced the tilde with hard-coded path and all is well again.